# JMS IBM MQ - limit the size of the returned message on browse

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

In my scenario the queue contains huge (32MB+) messages, and the data is structured such that the information that identifies the type of message, is contained in the first few bytes of the message.

When using the low-level Websphere MQ API it is possible to provide a buffer of a specific (limited) size, then issue the MQGET call with options that include the MQGMO_ACCEPT_TRUNCATED_MSG flag. The reason code returned by the MQGET would then probably be MQRC_TRUNCATED_MSG_ACCEPTED (which is to be expected).

This enables one to write a very fast "browse all" kind of logic that returns the first (lets say) 100 bytes of each message instead of the full buffer for each.

Is it possible to do something similar using java JMS? I have not been able to find anything that allows me to specify a buffer size on either the 
session.createBrowser(queue...) or the
browser.getEnumeration() calls.

Thanks.

Comment: Feels too specific to IBM MQ to me.  I have never seen such a thing in JMS.  Sounds like a bad design.  If you need to know message type, perhaps you ought to be using a topic for each message type.  Would something like this help you? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncfl/index.html

Comment: Thanks, I had a look at the link you provided. That is basically what I'm doing. The issue is that the normal way of browsing retuns all those huge messages which take a lot of resources.
The closest I got to a possible answer is this [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377185/spring-jms-ibm-mq-how-to-set-message-buffer-size-or-wait-timeout) - that post uses the  ibm mq specific jms api (i'm using the vanilla javax.jms classes). he got the mqrc_truncated_msg_failed, but it looks as if it was caused by a channel issue.

Comment: You have my sympathies dealing with IBM.  I'd prefer sticking to JMS and not binding myself too closely to Big Blue.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use `Message Selectors`. This will require the `JMSProducer` to set the message type as a property. A message selector cannot scan the payload, only the headers and properties.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The selector approach will enable me to go find a specified subset of the messages. This will not do. If I can use the analogy of an "inbox" where I need to populate the inbox with the sender/date/time/subject (which I can get from the first 100 bytes) without needing the complete message. Hope this explains what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting a pattern then defining your data, you have data and want to force it to fit a pattern.  That's a little backwards.

Questions:

(1) Are you putting different types of data into the same queue?  i.e. multiple and different type of senders?

(2) Is the sender (publisher) a JMS application?

(3) Are you trying to create an application that will move/filter messages like what IIB (Message Broker) would do?  If not, then what is the real purpose of your program?

---

Each unique application should have its own queue.  Queues should be handed out like candle to kids on Halloween.

i.e.  Lets say HR has the following 5 applications:

- Recruiting
- Payroll
- Benefits
- Training
- Employees

Do not create a queue called 'HR.Q' that will process all of the HR messages. Bad design, bad to support.

Rather each unique application should have its own queue.
i.e.

- 'HR.RECRUITING.Q'
- 'HR.PAYROLL.Q'
- 'HR.BENEFITS.Q'
- 'HR.TRAINING.Q'
- 'HR.EMPLOYEES.Q'

Comment: I totally agree. I am however trying to make a legacy system perform better, so my options are severely limited on the re-design front.
As to your questions:
  1) no
  2) no
  3) not sure what Message Broker does
All I'm trying to accomplish is to browse a lot of huge messages without having to retrieve the complete message buffer for each of them.
I can do this with the low-level IBM MQ API, I was hoping it is possible doing the same using vanilla JMS.

Comment: Why are you trying to read only the 1st 100 bytes or so?  Why not read the entire message and then process it?  Are you trying to determine if the application should process the message?  i.e. Are there messages in the queue that the application does not process?  i.e. You said 'no' to Q1.

Comment: The queue contains XML documents, the first 100 or so bytes contain sufficient information to populate an "inbox" of sorts, the message is only consumed/processed once a user selects the item he is interested in. 
I understand that the design is not optimal, but I do not have any influence on the message producers. . .

Comment: Are you moving the message to another queue?  If not, how is the information getting to the application's inbox?

Comment: User starts up a GUI, GUI code browse the queue and populate the inbox, user selects an item from the inbox. Selected item is then consumed from the queue.   I know the design is bad, it is not going to change soon. I am trying to find out if it is possible to get JMS to read a partial message, so that the "populate" logic does not have to browse complete messages.

Comment: I found another link that says it cannot be done [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933190/java-jms-slow-browsing-on-large-text-messages)